# Allowing Resize Only From Bottom-Right Corner

Tags: javascript, resize

Is it possible to allow users to resize the browser window only from the bottom right corner ? I am using `window.onresize = function () {};` but user can resize window from any side. I want to restrict that and only allow it from bottom right corner

Can a solution be implemented in JavaScript ?

Comment: JavaScript does not control the browser's behavior

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: It's a very good thing javascript cannot do this.

Comment: @TimRogers want to do that in order to maintain the aspect ratio

Comment: in that case, you may want to maintain the aspect ratio after each resizing event (with some throttling). But more to the point, you probably don't want to mess with the window size - only porn and casino sites do that now.